# Avoid error 'Parameter $arg could not be found in method()' on variable arguments methods on phpDocumetor

Tags: php, phpdoc

I've been recently documenting my classes, and one of them has a method with no arguments in its definition, but because I parse them with `get_func_args()`. Let me show you:

```
public function method()
{
    if(func_num_args() == 2)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem's that when I document it, I want to add which arguments it receives. Something like this:

```
/**
* Some info
* @param string $arg Some value
* @param mixed $arg2 Some value
*/
```

Before asking, I do this with the `get_func_args()` stuff because it extends an abstract class, whose arguments differ a little from each implementation.

When I document this class, it pops a notice:

```
Parameter $arg could not be found in method()
```

Any way to avoid this, or to tell phpDocumentor that this class has in fact some parameters?

Comment: are you trying to overload the function?

Comment: Maybe [internal](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.internal.pkg.html) would help? `@internal @param string $arg`

Comment: @Hanut Nope, it is just a [Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). In the abstract class it holds undefined parameters, yet in each extension its parameter amount may vary

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov I'd like the parameter definition to show up in the documentation, precisely because they "aren't there" when the method is defined.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to review your architecture and match arguments in abstract and children classes.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov I feared that, unfortunately... Well, if you add this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to review your architecture and match arguments in abstract and children classes, because PHPDoc seems to be strict about parameters given in annotations.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, it's such a pity that, in these cases, there is no method to surpass the documentation rules.

Comment: Indeed, if you're extending an abstract class and overwriting a methods implementation you need to keep the same signature otherwise you're breaking the OOP model by not implementing your own interfaces.